# loop through every row in table

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

Price is a column in my database that is set based on a vendor's entry.

I export the vendor's account information including price to a gridview in asp.net and i want to directly modify the price cell based on criteria entered by a customer. for instance, if the customer lives outside of the state, shipping will cost more. the shipping cost is fixed by the vendor and is stored in the same table as price. All two letter abbreviations below represent criteria that determine price increases.

The gridview queries the database based on the selected product. I want to run a query for every vendor listed in the vendor table (seeing as multiple vendors may offer the same product)

```
i = GridView1.Rows.Count

For x As Integer = 0 (where x is the current row) To i (where i is the number of rows in the table)
    (If Session("GH") = "Yes" Then Price = Price * cell
    +
    If Session("DH") = "Yes" Then Price = Price * cell
    +
    If Session("CD") = "Yes" Then Price = Price * cell)
    --------------------------------------------------                   
    divided by the number of questions answered "Yes"
    x = x + 1
 Next()
```

Each iteration would adjust the price for one vendor, there are many vendors.

Comment: Don't modify the `GridView`. Modify the data that you _bound_ to the `GridView`.

Comment: yes that is something i have thought about but the question still remains as how to modify all of the data by running the same query for each row and then how to store that data in a gridview

Comment: you don't store data in a gridview. gridview is only for display. And of course you need sql update statement on each iteration to modify each row in the database table

Comment: Another way is to intercept the data in the RowDataBoundEvent.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox ty. ty for the info about gridview. i am not trying to update the database but i am trying to select from it. steve, ty i will look into it